# Issue extracting text from pdf with PyPDF2

Tags: python, pypdf

I am trying to use the PyPDF2 module to read text from a pdf document. When I call the `extractText()` function on a page object it is causing this error for some pdfs. This is the traceback from after the point where I call the function. I don't understand why this happens with some pdfs, but not others. All of the pdfs that I am reading from I am able to select/search for text in. I can't give any examples of the pdfs unfortunately.

```
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 2595, in extractText
    content = ContentStream(content, self.pdf)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 2674, in __init__
    self.__parseContentStream(stream)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 2706, in __parseContentStream
    operands.append(readObject(stream, None))
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\generic.py", line 66, in readObject
    return DictionaryObject.readFromStream(stream, pdf)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\generic.py", line 582, in readFromStream
    elif pdf.strict:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strict'
```

When I `print` the page object that I am calling `extractText()` on I get this output:

```
{'/Tabs': '/S', '/Group': {'/S': '/Transparency', '/Type': '/Group', '/CS': '/DeviceRGB'}, '/Contents': [IndirectObject(1, 0), IndirectObject(9, 0), IndirectObject(10, 0), IndirectObject(11, 0), IndirectObject(2, 0)], '/Type': '/Page', '/Resources': {'/ExtGState': {'/GS7': IndirectObject(12, 0), '/GS8': IndirectObject(13, 0)}, '/ProcSet': ['/PDF', '/Text', '/ImageB', '/ImageC', '/ImageI'], '/XObject': {'/Xi6': IndirectObject(3, 0), '/Xi4': IndirectObject(14, 0), '/Xi5': IndirectObject(15, 0), '/Xi2': IndirectObject(16, 0), '/Xi3': IndirectObject(17, 0), '/Image22': IndirectObject(18, 0), '/Image11': IndirectObject(19, 0)}, '/Font': {'/F7': IndirectObject(20, 0), '/Xi1': IndirectObject(21, 0), '/F1': IndirectObject(22, 0), '/F2': IndirectObject(23, 0), '/F3': IndirectObject(24, 0), '/F4': IndirectObject(25, 0), '/F5': IndirectObject(26, 0), '/F6': IndirectObject(27, 0)}, '/Properties': {'/Xi0': IndirectObject(28, 0)}}, '/StructParents': 0, '/Parent': IndirectObject(29, 0), '/MediaBox': [0, 0, 612, 792]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that your "pdf" variable is None. Check that the pdf page exists

Comment: That is not my `pdf` variable, that is something in the package itself. I have no control over that variable, and if it was an issue with the page I am working on being `NoneType` it would have a different error.

Comment: Yes, i know, but the package pypdf is saying that is not finding the pdf. Debug your code  and check the variable where you are calling extractText()

Comment: I added the output of `print` on one of the page objects that I am using to the post.